# EditText in AlertDialog does not look like an EditText in Dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-appcompat

I have a normal Dialog with an EditText:
http://imageshack.com/a/img673/4729/UPuwot.png

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Player 1 name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"/>
```

And I have an AlertDialog with an EditText:
http://imageshack.com/a/img537/416/jmkW6r.png

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:hint="custom score"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

How can I make both look the same. I prefer the AlertDialog's layout. I use AppCompat 21.

Moreover, I think i can remember that in the beginning of programming, all EditTexts looked the same. Then I started playing around with themes and now there is this problem.

Comment: Can you show more about your codes?

Comment: Set layout parameter while setting in alert dialog,WrapContent

Comment: I added the EditText xmls

Comment: Okay. When I use only the AlertDialog, there will be no problem